# How to enable relationships in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, relationships

I know very little about MySQL, and PHPMyAdmin, I have am going to make a quiz program in PHP, it will allow the user(s) to create, save and do multiple choice quizzes.

The way in which the tables are currently structured (I'm open to suggestions, if this structure sounds rubbish:) )
I've got 3 tables, 
**Quizzes** containing:

```
 ID, quiz title and quiz_ID,
```

**Answers** containing:

```
 ID, question_ID, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4 and correct answer
```

**Questions** containing:

```
 ID, and the question.
```

I have absolutle no idea at all where to start in creating relationships to join ip various ID's. I am using PHPMyAdmin, and have looked around, and it says the relationship reature is disabled. So I think the first thing I need to do is enable this feature.

I would be so grateful for any help at all, and please explain it clearly because I'm pretty thick at all this :p

Thanks again in advance :) xx

Comment: tables should use innoDB engine to enable foreign keys, that should get you started :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the structure view of a table you have a link just below the list saying "Relation view".

Also make sure you have indexed the field you want to make relation on

Answer (score 0):

[Link to tutorial](http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000043.html#.ToyqrIZJzfw).

It is meant for use on a webserver, but it should help you further. If you can modifiy config.inc.php, you of course don't have to install pma again.

Please note that you can easily join tables using `JOIN`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but the phpmyadmin relationships feature is only going to be useful if the clients have access to the phpmyadmin interface. Are these features useful to the end-user if the OP is writing a custom web-based interface to add records?

Comment: I believe not. if you want to join tables, the simple way is to use {JOIN}